# How can I make a Web App use its actual path, instead of a Temporary ASP.NET path

Tags: asp.net

I have a Web App that cannot find a dll it depends on.
In the past this web app would be run from the directory it is installed in.
The sxstrace of the old version shows:

```
ManifestPath = C:\Program Files\CompanyName\DecodingService\cpbin\CoordSystems.Internal.Translation.dll
```

After upgrading to a newer version of .NET it now runs the web app from what I assume is a cached or compiled directory, sxstrace shows this for the new version:

```
ManifestPath = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\decodingservice\b3438ba3\458e37dc\assembly\dl3\d7baeb04\00720865_2e07d501\CoordSystems.Internal.Translation.DLL
```

When it 'compiles' the web app and places things in the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory it is missing a manifest that points to a native dll.
If I could get it to run out of the path I deploy it in, instead of the compiled "Temporary ASP.NET Files" path, it will be able to find the manifest and load the native dll.
How can I stop it from copying or compiling to the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory?
Note that an alternate solution would be to get the manifest into the that directory, but the manifest name does not match the name of the dll that it is associated with and I assume that is why it doesn't realize it should copy it.

Answer (score 0):

A distant colleague said that the temporary path is used for "shadowing" so searching for shadowing might have gotten me to the answer.  Here is how to stop shadowing:
Tell it to not shadow in the Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But something to note is that *I don't think* it automatically loads new assemblies after this, so you may have to iisreset or something to get it to use them after you change them in the web app.